# What is the best way to factorise this code in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to factorise this code (if/else).

In a first way, I do something like this :

```
  <% @pois.each_with_index do |poi, i| %>
        <div class="card-item">
          <% if poi.poitable.sleep_images.blank? %>
            <div class="card-sleep-thumb" style="background-image: url(<%= cl_image_path("comingsoon.jpg", :width=>600, :crop=>"scale") %>);">
          <% else %>
            <div class="card-sleep-thumb" style="background-image: url(<%= cl_image_path(poi.poitable.sleep_images.first.image, :width=>600, :crop=>"scale") %>);">
          <% end %>
```

In second way I try another think like this :

```
<div class="card-sleep-thumb" style="background-image: url(<%= if poi.poitable.sleep_images.blank? ? cl_image_path("comingsoon.jpg", :width=>600, :crop=>"scale" : cl_image_path(poi.poitable.sleep_images.first.image, :width=>600, :crop=>"scale") %>);" %>
```

But, maybe, there is a better way, with a method in my model ?

How can you do the same thing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User a Helper method

```
class SomeModelHelper
  def some_method_name(poi)
    if poi.poitable.sleep_images.blank?
      cl_image_path("comingsoon.jpg", :width=>600, :crop=>"scale")
    else
      cl_image_path(poi.poitable.sleep_images.first.image, :width=>600, :crop=>"scale")
    end
  end
end


// in the view

<div class="card-sleep-thumb" style="background-image: url(<%= some_method_name(poi).html_safe %>);" %>
```

Of course, you should use the helper associated with the `poi` class (e.g `PoiHelper` if the class is called `Poi`) and have a more expressive name for the helper method.

Comment: Thanks Tamer, I think, there is the better way ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `||` operator, which returns the first "truthy" operand, instead of the `if`/`else` you're currently using:

```
cl_image_path(poi.poitable.sleep_images.first&.image || "comingsoon.jpg")
```

This argument to `cl_image_path` will either be the image, if present, or `"comingsoon.jpg"`
otherwise.

A first pass of refactoring you could would look like this:

```
<% @pois.each do |poi| %>
  <div class="card-item">
    <div class="card-sleep-thumb" style="background-image: url(<%= cl_image_path(poi.poitable.sleep_images.first.image || "coming_soon.jpg"), :width=>600, :crop=>"scale") %>);">
    </div>
   </div>
 <% end %>
```

However, you can clean this up a lot by dropping `each` and using collection rendering.

Your existing view would look like this:

```
<%= render @pois %>
```

and you would make a new partial containing the HTML representation of a given "Poi". I don't know what the class name is, but if it is `Poi`, the partial should be placed in `app/views/pois/_poi.html.erb`, and it would contain the following:

```
<div class="card-item">
  <div class="card-sleep-thumb" style="background-image: url(<%= cl_image_path(poi.poitable.sleep_images.first.image || "coming_soon.jpg"), :width=>600, :crop=>"scale") %>);">
  </div>
</div>
```